# Attempting to delete a file crashes Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, windows-explorer, crash, windows-10-v1903

There's a file on my Desktop folder that I can't move (to another folder), delete or rename - it crashes *explorer.exe*.
I tried deleting this file before sleeping, but I couldn't. I figured I'd be able to do so after restarting - I'm not.

I created this file with FFMPEG by trimming a video with `-s nn -to nn`- this behavior with the file is unexpected.

I tried deleting it through *cmd* (`del /f`) and *Powershell* (`remove-item`)  but both programs gave no output - after pressing enter, the caret kept blinking in the first empty line indefinitely. I ran them as admin.

I can't change permissions on it either (though I'm already the owner) - doing so also crashes `explorer`.

- **Product**: Windows 10 Pro
- **Version**: 1903
- **Build**: 10.0.18362.239

[image: File properties screenshot].

Event Viewer Reports for the crash:

- https://ybin.me/p/c09d83efac001fdd#UNYfsovPxHlcwMJtbiVrBeAw5UkF8Oke/jR76J5+tfo=
- https://ybin.me/p/c31a12cc4a4cce40#Me50AhFODFKT43tW/SArKt/NSneNkQquk+HNew6uudA=

Comment: Delete it using Windows command prompt.

Comment: @Moab As described in the question, I did try doing that.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Downloading LockHunter, clicking on *Unlock It!* fixed it. I was then able to permanently delete the file. Could you type that as the answer so you get the credit?

Comment: Open command prompt and don't close it, then open task manager and kill the Windows explorer process, then try the delete command again, then restart explorer using File>run new task, explorer.exe.

Comment: @Unknow0059, done, and I'm glad it helped. Out of curiosity, did you see what process had the file locked?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik yes, check the last link I edited into the question. It was dllhost - I don't understand why, however.

Comment: If you solved the question, please don't put that into the question, but simply accept the answer that gives the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [*LockHunter*](http://lockhunter.com),  or [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/lockhunter/), which can show how the file is being used.
A file generated by *ffmpeg* is probably safe to forcibly delete, but use caution on files that might be needed by the system.

Also, try checking the disk for errors -- full scan.